# CSS style checkbox inside td

Tags: html, css

i would like to set the checkbox inside a table to middle / center

the dirty way i am using is

```
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" style="text-align:center;" ng-model="x.dedbuffer">
</td>
```

However, i am looking a way that all the checbox inside the table will be centered. So i am come out with a css

```
.table td input[type="checkbox"] {
    text-align: center;
}
```

but the css is not working as expected. how to style it in css?

Comment: you have to center align the checkbox only?

Comment: Unstructured about you have been asked

Comment: @rajamaha yes, only checkboc because that cell only contain a checkbox which i want to be centered. css on the `td` will centered other cell as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set it on the `input`'s parent, in this case the `td`.

*Updated showing how-to when targeting only specific cells*

```
table td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 300px;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
table td.centered {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="centered">
      <input type="checkbox" style="text-align:center;" ng-model="x.dedbuffer">
    </td>

    <td>
      Not centered
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you have more content in same cell, add a wrapper

```css
table {
  width: 300px;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
table td div {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      
      <input type="checkbox" style="text-align:center;" ng-model="x.dedbuffer">

      <div>
        Not centered
      </div>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I just want a checbox column to be centered. Your code seems to center all contents.

Comment: @JosephGoh You have more content in same cell?

Comment: then add a class to the cells occupying the checkbox e.g. `cell-checkbox` to all tds containing a checkbox and then use that in the selector

Comment: @JosephGoh Updated my answer with 2 ways

Comment: is that possible without creating extra class  `.centered` i am looking to set the checkbox centered without adding a class to the `td`

Comment: end up by creating an extra class to get the result.

Comment: @JosephGoh: You can drop the class and use `nth-child`, i.e. `table td:nth-child(1) { text-align: center; }`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
td input[type="checkbox"] {
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    display:block;
    argin:0px auto;
}
```

Comment: it is not working, the checkbox move to top near to the top border of the `td`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function alerrt() {
    alert("I am centered! checkbox");
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 300px;
}
table td {
  min-width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  padding:5px;
}
table td lable{
margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="centered">
     <lable> please check </lable> <input type="checkbox" onclick="alerrt()" style="text-align:center;" ng-model="x.dedbuffer">
    </td>



  </tr>
</table>
```